# How to convert multiple integers at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion, integer

I want to improve the lines of this code. Specifically, the part where I convert all the strings values to integers. I want to reduce that line to a simpler one.

```
import sys

def main():
    try:
        
        A,B,C,D =input("Enter values A,B,C,D separated by a comma: ").split(",")

        A=int(A) # These lines convert all the values into integers.
        B=int(B)
        C=int(C)
        D=int(D)

        print("Accepted values") if (A>0 and B>0 and C>0 and D>0 and A%2==0 and B>C and C>D and C+D > A+B) else print("Non-accepted values")
          
    except ValueError:  
        sys.exit("Invalid input. You have not entered integer values correctly separated by a comma.\n Program ends.") 

if __name__== "__main__" :          
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 A,B,C,D =int(input("Enter values A,B,C,D separated by a comma: ")).split(",")
```

You have to just add int before input...

That's solve

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in function [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to apply a function (such as `int`) to each item in a sequence.

```
a,b,c,d = map(int, input("Enter values: ").split(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to accomplish that.

```
numbers = input("Please Enter A number seperated by comma").split(",")
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    numbers[i] = int(numbers[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what is looking for:

```
A,B,C,D =list(map(int,input("Enter values A,B,C,D separated by a comma: ").split(",")))
```